# How do I Add User or Edit a Password on Solr 6.6 on Windows

Tags: windows, solr

How do I **Add User or Edit a Password** on Solr 6.6 on Windows for basic authentication plugin using PowerShell's invoke-webrequest command?

Reference: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/basic-authentication-plugin.html#BasicAuthenticationPlugin-AddaUserorEditaPassword

thanks

Comment: Those examples are for curl, not for the `post` tool. The `post` tool is used for indexing content in Solr, not for general API requests.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how I could use PowerShell's invoke-webrequest? I've tried that as well, but I'm not familiar with PowerShell.

Comment: In that case it's probably easier to just download curl for Windows.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize curl for Windows existed. However, I'm unable to run it on the server due to Symantec's "Security risk detected: WS.Reputation.1" which I'm unable to disable/get around and also blocked because it's not whitelisted from running in my local/laptop environment. PowerShell would be the best alternative, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Used Curl for Windows as recommended by @MatsLindh

```
curl --basic --user solrAdmin:adminPassword 
    --url http://<server>:8983/solr/admin/authentication 
    --header 'Content-type:application/json' 
    --data "{'set-user':{'user1':'password1','user2':'password2'}}"
```

Curl for Windows downloaded at https://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=bin

Initially, I had a few errors and I had to switch the double and single quotes in the data/body from the example provided on Solr 6.6 documentation (link in question).

Comment: The single vs double quotes is a thing with cmd / psh under Windows